effect of drain inductor of LNA on swing
i have a problem with putting an inductor in drain of an LNA if we put an inductor it would be short circuit in DC so it would not have any swing and it can not properly amplify our input signal and even if we say that the inductor has a series resistor that would be too small .can that small voltage drop on the small resistor(maybe somthing less than 10 ohm)
satisfy the swing needed for signal after amplification ?


The purpose of a LNA is to amplify AC (RF) signals and not a DC voltage. For AC (RF) signal the reactance of Lbias is key.

thanks . but the signal must be amplified if it can not go up and down properly lets say it reaches vdd wouldn't it be distorted? so i thought it needs a dc level of maybe vdd-10mv   (since input is small maybe in range of micro volt and amplified to mv) so it wont be distored

For RF signals Lbias (e.g. 22nH with XL=138 Ohm @ 1GHz) is the drain "resistor". Contrary to a normal resistor, Lbias stores energy during the negative half wave and is releasing that energy during the positive half wave. The amplified RF voltage will swing symmetrically up and down the 1.5V DC voltage present at the drain.

thank you very much
